# Unlock VTC queue

Tags: feature-request, review

In the new Review queue, it shows a section for Vote to Close. It gets greyed out when you run out of close votes, but sometimes one can go in and Edit a question so it wouldn't be closed. **I propose that the queue gets unlocked, but only for a <kbd>Do Not Close</kbd>, <kbd>Not Sure</kbd> or <kbd>Edit</kbd> vote** when the user has run out of votes

Comment: As soon as this is implemented, someone's going to come to Meta to ask "why can't I vote to close questions anymore," and follow up with "don't show me a nerfed VTC queue if I'm out of close votes for the day."

Comment: I believe it would be the same as the "You can't vote for your own questions/answers, so take away the arrows"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea behind rate-limiting here is to prevent someone from just blazing through the whole queue without really putting much thought into what they're doing. If someone's thoughtlessly voting to close, then giving them another button to thoughtlessly click (Do Not Close) isn't a great idea.

Note that editing itself isn't really rate-limited: you can edit as much as you want. And you can edit *from the close review queue* as much as you want, until you run out of close votes.

If you really want to climb that leaderboard, edit *whenever* possible. Leave close and do-not-close as a last resort, for questions that cannot be improved.

If you burn through all of your votes before you're sick of editing... Well, it's really not hard to find questions to edit.

Comment: I mainly go on SuperUser, and I would say about 75% of my close votes are shopping recommendations which are off topic there; that's why I usually run out of close votes

Comment: @CanadianLuke Maybe a better solution would be to refund close votes for certain frequently-close-voted questions.  But considering DIamond Mods can close questions immediately if they're obviously off-topic, it might not be entirely necessary.